# Is generate Guaranteed to be Executed Sequentially?

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda, language-lawyer, sequential

I was told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280217/how-to-use-algorithms-to-fill-vector-of-vectors/33282441?noredirect=1#comment54361802_33280760) that:

> The order of generate is not guaranteed => depending on the implementation

I have looked up [gcc's implementation of `generate`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a01045_source.html#l05012):

```
  for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
*__first = __gen();
```

And Visual Studio implements it identically to that. This is a relief to me as using a lambda in `generate` that reads and writes to a capture could have undeterministic results:

```
int foo[] = {1, 0, 13};
vector<int> bar(3);

generate(bar.begin(), bar.end(), [&]() {
    static auto i = 0;
    static auto total = 0;

    total += foo[i];
    return foo[i] / total;
});
```

[I expect](http://ideone.com/McpA4U) `bar` to contain `{1, 0, 0}`.

If I am allowed to execute out of order this could even cause a divide by 0 error.

So I'd sleep easier if this question could be answered with proof that `generate` is required to execute sequentially.

As a note here, I know that [`experimental::parallel::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing#generate) will not be sequential. I'm just asking about `generate`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why std::transform doesn't guarantee the order (but for\_each guarantee the order)? Doesn't this allow trick implementation for performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356719/why-stdtransform-doesnt-guarantee-the-order-but-for-each-guarantee-the-order)

Comment: after doing a little research (and some lateral thought) I can confirm that std::generate is guaranteed to be sequential. answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was intrigued by this so have done some research.

At the bottom of this answer is a copy of the relevant section from the standard as of 2011.

You will see from the template declaration of `std::generate<>` that the iterator parameters must conform to the concept of a `ForwardIterator` and `OutputIterator` respectively.

A ForwardIterator *does not support random access*. it can only read or write sequentially. An `OutputIterator` is even more restrictive - its `operator*` implicitly includes the effect of an `operator++`. This is an explicit feature of the concept.

Therefore, by implication, the implementation of this function *must* access elements sequentially (and therefore generate values sequentially) since *to not do so would break the contract implicit in the interface*.

Therefore the standard **does** (implicitly and quietly) guarantee that `std::generate` initialise its elements sequentially. It would be impossible to write a well-formed implementation of `std::generate` that did not.

QED

> 25.3.7 Generate [alg.generate]

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class Generator>
void generate(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
Generator gen);

template<class OutputIterator, class Size, class Generator>
OutputIterator generate_n(OutputIterator first, Size n, Generator gen);
```

> 1 Effects: The first algorithm invokes the function object gen and
> assigns the return value of gen through all the iterators in the range
> [first,last). The second algorithm invokes the function object gen and
> assigns the return value of gen through all the iterators in the range
> [first,first + n) if n is positive, otherwise it does nothing.
>
> 2
> Requires: gen takes no arguments, Size shall be convertible to an
> integral type (4.7, 12.3).
>
> 3 Returns: generate_n returns first + n for
> non-negative values of n and first for negative values.
>
> 4 Complexity:
> Exactly last - first, n, or 0 invocations of gen and assignments,
> respectively.

Comment: Whew I can sleep again at night. I knew that about `ForwardIterator`s but I never put much thought into it, that's actually really important in this situation isn't it. The linked [std::transform doesn't guarantee the order (but for_each guarantee the order)? Doesn't this allow trick implementation for performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356719/why-stdtransform-doesnt-guarantee-the-order-but-for-each-guarantee-the-order) also makes the same mistake. It'd be worthwhile to go post an answer there, or at least a comment with a link to this answer.

Comment: @RichardHodges +1 Overlooked that too ... well, generate got just usable again :D

Comment: Algorithms can be optimised to different iterator categories.

Comment: @curiousguy optimise yes, but change observable behaviour no. The algorithm's interface mandates ForwardIterator. Therefore to detect that it really is a random access iterator and use it (illogically) as such would change the observable behaviour of the function template.

Comment: @RichardHodges What is observable behaviour?

Comment: for example "this function fills the range between one **forward iterator** and another". There is an unequivocal implicit implication that the function will iterate forwards, since its interface is presented in terms of forward iterators and the documentation must be read in that light. If there was an intention that it could optionally iterate backwards (or randomly) this would be explicitly made clear by the function being declared in terms of random access iterators. This would give rise to the possibility of different observable behaviour (generated values landing in different positions).

Answer (score 1):

Here is all the standard says about it (25.7.3/1):

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class Generator>
void generate(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Generator gen);

template<class OutputIterator, class Size, class Generator>
OutputIterator generate_n(OutputIterator first, Size n, Generator gen);
```

> The first algorithm invokes the function object
>   gen
>   and assigns the return value of
>   gen
>   through
>   all the iterators in the range
>   [first,last)
>   . The second algorithm invokes the function object
>   gen
>   and assigns the return value of
>   gen
>   through all the iterators in the range
>   [first,first + n)
>   if
>   n
>   is
>   positive, otherwise it does nothing.

As you can see, it is not explicitly stated that the iterator assignments must be done sequentially.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that you saw [Richard Hodges answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33305627/2642059), it is in conflict with your, but I believe his answer is correct.