# Capturing a Lambda's static in a Nested Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++14, capture

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33282441/2642059) I use this code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> imat(3, std::vector<int>(10));

std::for_each(imat.begin(), imat.end(), [&](auto& i) {
    static auto row = 0;
    auto column = 0;
    std::transform(i.begin(), i.end(), i.begin(), 
        [&](const auto& /*j*/) {
            return row * column++; 
    }); 

    ++row; 
});
```

But I notice some misbehavior in capturing `static auto row` depending upon the compiler.

[Clang 3.7.0 yields](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe3ef266452f39fe):

> 0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>   0   2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18

[gcc 5.1.0 yields](http://ideone.com/NTLmV2):

> 0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

And Visual Studio 2015 gives me a compile time error:

> An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

If I change the capture nested capture to capture `row` explicitly I get the compiler error:

> identifier in capture must be a variable with automatic storage duration declared in the reaching scope of the lambda

Am I allowed to capture a `static` in a nested lambda? It seems legit, but there are so many problems!

**EDIT:**

[Fozi pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285103/capturing-a-lambdas-static-in-a-nested-lambda?noredirect=1#comment54371126_33285103) that I *can* get Visual Studio 2015 to compile and give the same output as Clang 3.7.0 if I change the nested lambda's parameter type from `const auto&` to `const int&`. Which seems completely unrelated, but it works.

This doesn't work if I try to capture `row` explicitly. In that case I still get the compiler error:

> identifier in capture must be a variable with automatic storage duration declared in the reaching scope of the lambda

I've reported a Visual Studio 2015 bug here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1930409/capturing-a-lambdas-static-in-a-nested-lambda

Comment: @865719 Hmmm, I can't seem to find the fix you're talking about, but I'm gonna update my Visual Studio 2015 and try again.

Comment: @865719 My Visual Studio 2015 is up to date according to Windows Update. Incidentally I'm also able to replicate the bug by pasting the code into: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: It compiles if you change `const auto& /*j*/` to `const int& /*j*/`

Comment: @Fozi Excellent call. I have no idea how you found that it seems completely unrelated. I added an edit to my question. Seems like this is still a bug with the captures.

Comment: GCC 5.2.0 compiles it correctly.

Comment: @Jason Compiles and runs it correctly? That's probably additional useful information. I wonder what changed between the minor versions?

Comment: Actually, GCC 5.2.0 is also incorrect (http://goo.gl/4HqHQR).  It's missing the `inc`.

Comment: @Jason Yeah I just ran it here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/ I'm getting the same result as gcc 5.1.0. The full matrix of 0s.

Comment: For VS2013, it seems get correct result if change `[&](auto& i)` to `[&](std::vector<int>& i)`

Comment: @zangw You also have to change the nested lambda's parameter type from `const auto& /*j*/` to `const int& /*j*/` right? I didn't think that Visual Studio 2013 supported `auto` lambda parameters.

Comment: @JonathanMee, you are right. I have changed the parameter type as you said.

Comment: Still a bug in VS2017 Update 4, as can be seen with this demo code: https://godbolt.org/g/hnJwwy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Internal Compiler Error(*ICE*) is always a bug.

We don't need to capture variables of static storage duration but we do need to capture automatic variables that are [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use). From the draft C++ standard section `5.1.2`:

> The lambda-expression’s compound-statement yields the function-body (8.4) of the function call operator,
>   **but for purposes of name lookup (3.4)**, determining the type and value of this (9.3.2) and transforming idexpressions
>   referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using (*this) (9.3.1),
>   **the compound-statement is considered in the context of the lambda-expression.**

so `row` should be visible within the inner lambda and:

> [...]If a lambda-expression
>   or an instantiation of the function call operator template of a generic lambda odr-uses (3.2) this or a
>   variable with automatic storage duration from its reaching scope, that entity shall be captured by the
>   lambda-expression.[...]

Capture is only required for `this` and variables of automatic storage duration if they are odr-used and we can see that explicit capture is only defined for automatic variables or *this*:

> The identifier in a simple-capture is looked up using the usual rules for unqualified name lookup (3.4.1);
>   each such lookup shall find an entity. An entity that is designated by a simple-capture is said to be explicitly
>   captured, **and shall be this or a variable with automatic storage duration declared in the reaching scope of
>   the local lambda expression.**

For both Visual Studio and gcc to match the results of clang I can move `row` out to the global namespace, [see it live for gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eymPX8tI2KK2jQ09). Also as Fozi points out changing `const auto& /*j*/` to `const int& /*j*/` makes it start working.

It looks like gcc accepts explicit capture of non-automatic variables as an extension and even then explicitly capturing `row` for example `[&, &row](const auto & )` still produces all zeros.

Further for gcc if I move the definition for `row` to `main` then I see the following error (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oZ8cRGniPT0RG06i)*):

```
/tmp/cchzwtQI.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cchzwtQI.s:1572: Error: symbol `_ZL3row' is already defined
```

Which seems like a compiler error to me.

I don't see any portion of the standard that would make the original program ill-formed. Nor should changing the `auto` to `int` make a difference and non of the changes introduced by [polymorphic lambda proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3649.html) would seem to explain this difference either.

Comment: Did you see the [comment @Fozi made](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285103/capturing-a-lambdas-static-in-a-nested-lambda/33289327#comment54371126_33285103)? This code runs and produces the correct result in Visual Studio 2015: `for_each(imat.begin(), imat.end(), [&](auto& i) { static auto row = 0; auto column = 0; transform(i.begin(), i.end(), i.begin(), [&](const int& /*j*/) { return row * column++; }); ++row; });`

Comment: Can you remind me what "variables that are odr-used" means? That's One Definition Rule? Wouldn't all variables be odr-used then?

Comment: @JonathanMee "odr-used" is roughly equivalent to "necessitates the entities existence at runtime".

Comment: @JonathanMee I added a link to my answer with an odr-use reference. Since we don't need to capture static variables it does not matter for them.

Comment: @JonathanMee you know Fozi was correct, it seems that webcompiler times out a lot and I was mistaking that for failure but after trying several times it did work with that change.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour You say "we don't need to capture `static` variables." Does that mean file scope `statics` or like function scope `statics`?